# how to get data from hidden app using PC?

Tags: android, apk

i have a app in my mobile which hide photos or apks and show when we enter the password in calculator. But the screen of the phone is broken and i cant use the phone and I want data which is stored in that hidden app. Is there any way to get that data using pc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it possible belongs on [android.SE]

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, your phone is broken and you are unable to enter the **password** to access your hidden files. So you want to remotely control your phone using a computer.

If this is true, here are some approaches that can help you,

1. [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/)
2. [TeamViewer Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market&hl=en_IN)

Although, **enter the password in calculator** was great. Buy yourself a cookie if you made it.

Try visiting [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) to ask such type of questions.